# How does $ \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2} \geq |xy|$ come from $ \frac{x + y}{2} \geq \sqrt{xy}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I know that the AM-GM inequality takes the form $$ \frac{x + y}{2} \geq \sqrt{xy},$$ but I read in a book another form which is $$ \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2} \geq |xy|,$$ but I am wondering how the second comes from the first? could anyone explain this for me, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you plug $x=X^2$, $y=Y^2$ into the first inequality you get
$$\frac{X^2+Y^2}{2} \ge  \sqrt{X^2Y^2} = \sqrt{(XY)^2}=|XY|,$$
which is the second inequality (modulo capitalization).

Answer (score 5):

The AM-GM inequality for $n$ non-negative values is

$\frac1{n}(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k)
\ge (\prod_{k=1}^n x_k)^{1/n}
$.

This can  be rewritten in two ways.

First,
by simple algebra,

$(\sum_{k=1}^n x_i)^n
\ge n^n(\prod_{k=1}^n x_k)
$.

Second,
letting $x_k = y_k^n$,
this becomes

$\frac1{n}(\sum_{k=1}^n y_k^n)
\ge \prod_{k=1}^n y_k
$.

It is useful to recognize
these disguises.